# how to wrap a form generated by webform in a div?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I am using Drupal now. is it possible to wrap the form generated by the community webform module in a div? any theming method or hook point to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a div around form by hook_page_alter, for example:

```
function hook_page_alter(&$page) {
  // Add help text to the user login block.
  $page['content']['...']['form'] = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div>', 
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );
}
```